# Symfony 5.3 - PhpStorm shows getUsername is deprecated, use getUserIdentifier

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, deprecation-warning

I have an index page which shows all users.
I get the users from the database via `$userRepository->findAll()` and transfer the data to the twig file:

```php
public function index(UserRepository $userRepository): Response
    {
        return $this->render('user/index.html.twig', [
            'users' => $userRepository->findAll(),
        ]);
    }
```

In the twig file I iterate through the users and display them all.

Now PhpStorm shows me, when using `{{user.username}}` that `Method 'user:getUsername'` is deprecated.
I checked within the UserEntity and yes, there is the `function getUsername` and the new `geUserIdentifier`.

I also checked the [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-3-improvements-for-security-users). However, since I don't use the `getUsername` function directly, but `findAll()`, I don't know how to approach the problem.

What and where do I have to change something, so that the new `getUserIdentifier` is used within `findAll()`?

Comment: I don't think findAll has anything to do with this.  Just update your twig template to use {{ user.useridentifier }}

Comment: @Cerad Thanks! I haven't thought of that. It works. What confuses me, is that if I dump the user array, username is there, that's why I was using user.username.

Anyway, I thought I can remove getUsername, but I cannot remove it from the UserEntity, since I get the following error:
```Fatal error: Class App\Entity\User contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface::getUsername)```
I will leave it as it is atm, but I really would like to know how to get rid of the deprecated function.

Comment: It is a transitional thing.  Starting in 6.0, getUsername() will be completely removed from UserInterface and the problem will go away.  Until then, you need getUsername for backwards compatibility even if you never call it.  Deprecation notices are annoying but you can in fact just ignore them.